# Subir mismo versionCode para mobile y wearable

Tags: android, android-wear

Estoy intentando subir una aplicación a Google Play la cual tiene versión para dispositivos móviles y también para Wear OS. Estoy intentando subirla pero cuando subo el bundle y después quiero activarla en tipos de versión para añadir el bundle de Wear OS, se queja de que el bundle tiene el mismo versionCode.

Mi duda es... ¿tengo que tener obligatoriamente diferentes versionCode en cada una? ¿No hay ninguna forma de subir un mismo paquete y que también esté disponible para Wear OS o que al menos se pueda usando el mismo versionCode?

Comment: Debes usar un diferente versionCode, ya que ambas tendrán el mismo packagename , aunque una es configurada solo para dispositivos  "Wear OS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede agregar otro tipo de versión de tu .APK, para esto desde la consola [Google Play](https://play.google.com/console/) ve a "Configuración", ingresa a la página "Configuración avanzada". En la pestaña "Tipos de versión", haz clic en Agregar tipo de versión que en este caso sería "Wear OS".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la versión wearable se define:

```
 <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
```

Esto para que desde Google Play, solo pueda entregar este tipo de aplicación para relojes.

Pero en cuanto al `versionCode`, este debe ser único, te sugiero revisar [Distribución para relojes Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/packaging?hl=es-419#distribution), que indica:

**El esquema de código de versión de un reloj APK puede ser independiente del de un teléfono APK. Su `versionCode` también debe ser único.**

Comment: En el caso de que mi aplicación de Wear OS sea dependiente de una de teléfono, no tendría que añadir ese parámetro en el Manifest, o también?

Comment: Ese valor es solo para la version Wear OS https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#device-ui-hw-features